# the number of distinct subrings of $\mathbb{Q}$ is infinite without using infiniteness of prime numbers

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, localization

I know all subrings of $\mathbb{Q}$ is ｛$\mathbb{Zs}$｜$\mathbb{S}$ is complement of union of $\mathbb{pZ}$ where $p$ is a prime｝.

If the number of prime numbers is finite, the number of distinct subring of $\mathbb{Q}$ is also finite.
If we could prove infinity of the number of distinct subrings of $\mathbb{Q}$ without using the fact that there are infinitely many primes, we can recover the proof of infiniteness of prime numbers.

So, I am seeking the proof of the title.Thank you for your help.

Comment: Any subring of $\mathbb{Q}$ contains $1$ and is closed under addition, so it must contain all of $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Are you asking whether there are infinitely many distinct subrings of $\Bbb{Q}$? As Nathan Lowry pointed out, any subring is, itself, automatically an infinite set. Please clarify.

Comment: Mind you, the proofs for there being infinitely many subrings I can think of all revolve around the fact that there are infinitely many primes :-/

Comment: This is basically equivalent to the infinitude of the primes; I don’t see that this rephrasing buys you anything.